# Recursing through a SQLite table to find a matching subset of records

Tags: sqlite, recursion

I have a table with 3 text fields column (A, B & C) imported from a flat file comprising many thousands of lines.  None of these fields have a UNIQUE constraint and there is no primary key combination.  As a result one or more records may have the same values and there will even be records with the same values across all fields.  In many records, columns A, B and C should be the same but due to data quality issues, column C has many variant where column A and B are the same.  Where column A and B are the same the corresponding value in column C may be subsets of the value of column C in another record having the same values as other records for column A and B.

To illustrate a subset arrived at by using GROUP BY gives:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSLny.png)

I now need to narrow down that subset further to find all records where the value in column C is INSTR the values of the other grouped results i.e. i'd like to return:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaUgu.png)

because "Buckingham" and "Lindsey" are both INSTR the records that contain "Lindsey Buckingham" in column C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `EXISTS` and `INSTR()`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where a = t.a and b = t.b and c <> t.c and instr(c, t.c) > 0
)
```

or with `LIKE`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where a = t.a and b = t.b and c <> t.c and c like '%' || t.c || '%'
)
```

or with a self join:

```
select distinct t.* 
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.a = t.a and tt.b = t.b and tt.c <> t.c and tt.c like '%' || t.c || '%'
```